# Replace two patterns at the same regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace one or two letters in a string in javascript but the letter is the same, then if I replace one of the two appareances the format is not correct:

```
HH:mm z [on] D MMM YYYY
HH:mm zz [on] D MMM YYYY
```

In the first case in example z should be replaced by CEST and with zz by Central European Summer Time.

I tried with regex but it is possible to replace the exact occurrence of first pattern without affecting to the second pattern?

Comment: What are the two replacements here and can you include them in your question?

Comment: The replacements are z and zz.

Comment: yourstring.replace(/\bz\b/g, 'CEST') // will replace 'z' but not 'zz'

Comment: If you use the regular expression `\bzz\b|\bz\b`, `'zz'` will be matched if present, else `'z'` will be matched if present. You can then replace the match depending on what was matched. Note that the alternation must attempt to match `'zz'` first; `\bz\b|\bzz\b` will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not worth a regexp - just do two replaces or loop `{zz:"Central European Summer Time",z:"CEST"}` to replace the zz first

```js
let str = `HH:mm z [on] D MMM YYYY
HH:mm zz [on] D MMM YYYY`

Object.entries({zz:"Central European Summer Time",z:"CEST"})
  .forEach(([key,val]) => str = str.replaceAll(key,val))
console.log(str)
```

Comment: It works fine. I was trying to replace several groups at same time with regexp, but this is a great option for that purpose.